# Move Gitlab to new ip-adress, lfs stop working. How to fix?

Tags: git, gitlab

We have GitLab 11.2.1-ee installation in our local network
It had ip-address 192.168.1.100 before
We use Git LFS in our projects
And all work fine before we changed ip address of Gitlab machine.
We changed the ip-adress of Gitlab machine to 192.168.160.160 and LFS stop working
Now it shows error

```
Error downloading object: some/object/path: Smudge error: Error downloading some/object/path (HASH_OF_OBJECT): batch response: Post http://192.168.1.100/root/PROJECT.git/info/lfs/objects/batch: dial tcp 192.168.1.100:80: connect: network is unreachable
```

We changed address of gitlab on clients to new one.
Also we changed external_url in gitlab.rb
Our git projects that do not use lfs works fine.
Only projects with LFS shows this error

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fix it.
I miss that I must run

```
sudo gitlab-ctl reconfigure
sudo gitlab-ctl restart
```

after editing external_url in /etc/gitlab/gitlab.rb
We run this commands and all is fine now